# Show that a conditional expectation is zero

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, continuous-data

Consider two binary random variables $G,Z$ and a continuous random variable $\eta$. Assume that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (A) \quad E(\eta|Z=1)=E(\eta|Z=0)=0\\
& (B) \quad  Pr(G=1| Z=1, \eta)=1 \quad \text{a.s.}
\end{aligned}
$$

Assuming also that the following expectations exist, which of them must be $0$?
\begin{aligned}
&(1)\quad E(\eta G| Z=1)\\
&(2) \quad E(\eta G Z)=0\\
&(3) \quad E(\eta Z| G=1)\\
& (4) \quad E(\eta| Z=1, G=1)\\
\end{aligned}

---

**MY ATTEMPTS (The question has been revised thanks to the comments below)**

For simplicity of notation, I assume that $\eta$ is discrete.

**(1):** Let $\mathcal{M}_1\equiv \{a\in \mathbb{R}: \Pr(\eta=a|Z=1)>0\}$.

We have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(\eta G |Z=1)& =\sum_{a\in \mathcal{M}_1} a \Pr(\eta=a, G=1|Z=1)\\
& =\sum_{a\in \mathcal{M}_1} a \underbrace{\Pr(G=1|\eta=a, Z=1)}_{=1}\times \underbrace{\Pr(\eta=a|Z=1)}_{\text{$>0$ because $a\in \mathcal{M}_1$}}\\
&=E(\eta|Z=1)=0
\end{aligned}
$$

**(2):**  We have that

$$
\begin{aligned}
E(\eta G Z)& = E(E(\eta G Z|Z))\\
&=E(\eta G Z|Z=1)\Pr(Z=1)+E(\eta G Z|Z=0)\Pr(Z=0)\\
&=1\times E(\eta G |Z=1)\Pr(Z=1)+0\times E(\eta G |Z=0)\Pr(Z=0)\\
&=E(\eta G |Z=1)\Pr(Z=1)\\
&\overbrace{=}^{(1)}0
\end{aligned}
$$

I'm not sure (3) and (4) hold.

Comment: Is this a self-study question? In other words, would you like help in terms of hints and checking your approach?

Comment: No, it is not. I would like to get the full answers. Thanks

Comment: I don't agree that the expectation is necessarily 0 for (2). Suppose that $\eta$ is normally distributed with mean 0, $G$ is always 1, and $Z$ is 1 if $\eta > 0$ and 0 otherwise. Then the expectation of (2) is positive, because conditioning on $Z = 1$, we know that $\eta > 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I understand your example. It seems to me that (2) follows from the law of iterated expectations and I have added some details above. Which step is wrong in your opinion?

Comment: @TEX I suggest you check each equality in your derivation until you find one which does not hold for my counterexample. That's the wrong step.

Comment: Your example says $\eta>0 \rightarrow Z=1$. However, to prove your claim, I think you are using the other direction of the relation:  $Z=1\rightarrow \eta>0$. If I'm wrong, please provide an answer with proof and I'll reward it.

Comment: @TEX both directions hold in my counterexample, since I said "$Z$ is 1 if $\eta > 0$ **and 0 otherwise**". BTW if you don't mention my username with the "@fblundun" syntax in your replies here I don't get automatically notified of them.

Comment: @fblundun Thanks. Please see the revised proof of $(*)$, as there was a typo before. Anyway,  I suppose that the problematic step is in the proof of $(*)$.  To show that $E(G \eta|Z=1)=E(E(\eta G|Z=1,\eta))$, first note that $$E(G\eta|Z=1)= \sum_{a\in \mathcal{M}} a Pr(G=1, \eta=a|Z=1) $$ At this point, I use the decomposition $$Pr(G=1, \eta=a|Z=1)=Pr(G=1|Z=1,\eta=a)\times Pr(\eta=a|Z=1)$$ which can be done only if $$Pr(\eta=a|Z=1)$$ is a non-zero probability event for each $a\in \mathcal{M}$. In your example, this does not hold.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is **incorrect**. I made the incorrect assumption that
$$
E[\eta Z \mid Z=1] = E[\eta]
$$
when actually
$$
E[\eta Z \mid Z=1] = E[\eta \mid Z=1]
$$
since $\eta$ and $Z$ are not necessarily independent. This assumption is also incorrectly made in other instances in this answer.

---

Using the law of total expectation
$$
\begin{align}
E[\eta Z] &= p(Z=0) \cdot E[\eta Z \mid Z=0] + p(Z=1) \cdot E[\eta Z \mid Z=1] \\
&= p(Z=0) \cdot E[0] + p(Z=1) \cdot E[\eta] \\
&= p(Z=1) \cdot E[\eta] \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
E[\eta G \mid Z=1] &= p(G=0 \mid Z=1) \cdot E[\eta G \mid Z=1,G=0] + p(G=1 \mid Z=1) \cdot E[\eta G \mid Z=1,G=1] \\
&= p(G=0 \mid Z=1) \cdot E[0 \mid Z=1] + p(G=1 \mid Z=1) \cdot E[\eta \mid Z=1] \\
&= p(G=1 \mid Z=1) \cdot E[\eta \mid Z=1] \\
&= \int_{\eta} \eta \cdot p(G=1 \mid Z=1) \cdot p(\eta \mid G=1,Z=1) \ \text{d} \eta
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
p(\eta \mid G=1,Z=1) = \frac{p(G=1 \mid Z=1,\eta) \cdot p(\eta \mid Z=1) \cdot p(Z=1)}{p(G=1 \mid Z=1) \cdot p(Z=1)}
$$
And since
$$
p(G=1 \mid Z=1,\eta) = 1
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
E[\eta G \mid Z=1] &= \int_{\eta} \eta \cdot p(\eta \mid Z=1) \ \text{d} \eta \\
&= E[\eta \mid Z=1] \neq 0
\end{align}
$$
Similarly:
$$
\begin{align}
E[\eta Z \mid G=1] &= p(Z=0 \mid G=1) \cdot E[\eta Z \mid G=1,Z=0] + p(Z=1 \mid G=1) \cdot E[\eta Z \mid G=1,Z=1] \\
&= p(Z=0 \mid G=1) \cdot E[0 \mid G=1] + p(Z=1 \mid G=1) \cdot E[\eta \mid G=1] \\
&= p(Z=1 \mid G=1) \cdot E[\eta \mid G=1]
\end{align}
$$
It is safe to assume that this will also not be equal to 0, since it is already difficult to use the fact that
$$
p(G=1 \mid Z=1,\eta) = 1
$$
without making the expression more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. When proving $E(\eta Z)=0$, we have $$p(Z=0)E(0)+p(Z=1) E(\eta Z|Z=1)=p(Z=1) E(\eta |Z=1)$$ How do you replace $E(\eta|Z=1)$ with $E(\eta)$?

Comment: With regards to $E(\eta G |Z=1)$ and $E(\eta Z |G=1)$: you don't show that they are equal to zero. Are they or are they not?

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify your second question. As for your first question, what I am doing is replacing $E[\eta Z \mid Z=1]$ with $E[\eta]$, since it is given in the expectation that $Z=1$.

Comment: @mhdadk that replacement is wrong, because we don't know that $\eta$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: What are you talking about? You used this replacement when you wrote $E(\eta G |Z=1,\eta=a) = a E( G |Z=1,\eta=a)$ in your derivation. In fact, $E( G |Z=1,\eta=a) = E( G |Z=1)$, since the value of $\eta$ is given.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the answer is wrong. You are deleting certain conditional events without being allowed to.

Comment: $E(G|Z=1, \eta=a)\neq E(G|Z=1)$ in general, unless you prove it for this specific case!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Actually, you are correct. In hindsight, I was considering them as independent events, and it has been a while since I have dealt with dependent events. Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited the answer to state this, but I will keep it as a reminder.